# Calling of C functions with undefined number of parameters

Tags: c, function-call

Note this question does not refer to ellipsis.

Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    printf("I AM AWESOME\n");
}

main(void) {
    foo(1,2,3);
    foo();
return 0;
}
```

This program runs perfectly and provides the output.
However, in case of 'main', this works irrespective of

`main(void)`

or

`main()`

When, defining foo as

`foo(void)`

gives an error - "too many arguments".

If both are functions, shouldn't they also follow the same rules?

Comment: It doesn't work "perfectly" since you should get a warning about a missing function signature for `foo()`. The short answer is that `main` is special and different rules apply to it.

Comment: Is there any reason you would want to use `foo()`?  It will probably be removed in the next standard.

Comment: `main()` is Implementation defined behaviour, and implementations will normally accept it.  You should never use it, though.

Comment: By 'implementation defined', do you mean compiler difference?

Comment: The standard only allows explicitly `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Anything different is asking for trouble.  Compilers may allow different `main` signatures or not.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I tried that (function overloading in c++). The short reason is "a program must not have multiple entry points'.

Comment: btw, what about the _start thing?

Comment: c++ is a different story. `()` is the same as `(void)` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare a function without parameters it means to disable type checking and to use K&R calling convention. It does not mean that the function does not have parameters.

In ANSI when you want to explicitly say that the function does not have parameters, you need to declare it as fun(void).

Answer (score 0):

The `foo(void)` takes no arguments (!!!), whereas `foo()` takes an unspecified number of arguments!

Comment: That's what is my question, shouldn't main also take unspecified number of arguments? If not declared with void and no arguments, if declared with 'void'?

Comment: and, if that's the case, is 'foo() can be called with unspecified number of arguments', a bug or a feature?

Comment: Why you care of main function ? you don't call main with parameters, just calling foo(). It's irrespective of main as you've wrote because you didn't call it (the system calls it).

Comment: Doesn't the system call _Start which in turn calls main?

Comment: Yes, the OS calls _Start

Comment: A bug in the old language, and a deprecated feature now

Comment: Oh!! That's what. So it all reduces to a simple bug. Then why hasn't it still been removed(no pun intended)? Is it useful in any way?

Comment: @Kobip In fact, you can call `main();`

Comment: How? I mean, do you want to say that we can bypass the whole _Start thing? Won't we have to write our own compiler to do that? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: @kesarling As I said in another comment, it will be removed in C2x (hopefully).

Comment: K :) Let's Hope so

Comment: @kesarling You can call `main();` inside your program at any moment, and it is legal.  I don't know of any situation where this would be desired, though.  Maybe you can try it and have fun :)

Comment: Oh. That I know. I thought you were talking about bypassing the whole _start. Anyways, Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

the is also somethg else in C called variable number of arguments

```
 void foo(int x, ...)
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-length-argument-c/

Comment: respected sir/ma'am,Please read the note given at the start of the question carefully